# My laravel collective form is not submitting when I click submit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form in my blade template when I click submit button nothing is happing it is not going to my controller. 
this is the form

```
{{Form::open(['action' => ['HomeController@addcity'], 'method' => 'POST']) }} 

{!! Form::select('city_add', array("CAM" => "CAM","KL" => "KL","IPOH" => "IPOH"), 'S',['style'=>'   

 }'],['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'hotel_name']); !!}
{{Form::text('city_add',"CAM") }}
  {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

this is my route

```
Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@addcity');
```

My route controller

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: no, I am getting any error.

Comment: Could you plz add your route / controller code ?

Comment: I added it my controller

Comment: Does the rendered HTML look OK?  Your `::select` code is invalid, the `style` element includes just a `}`.

Comment: I changed it but still it is not submitting

Comment: @MamadouBellaDiallo why you don't inspect rendered HTML form and add it to your post so we could look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form `select` element like below:
You should not use same name for the select tag and input tag.

```
{{Form::open(['action' => ['HomeController@addcity'], 'method' => 'POST']) }} 

    {!! Form::select('city_option', array("CAM" => "CAM","KL" => "KL","IPOH" => "IPOH"),['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'hotel_name']); !!}
    {{Form::text('city_add',"CAM") }}
    {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And In controller( for the test )

```
public function addcity(Request $request )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($request->all());
    exit(); 
}
```

if you would like to add style in form element use below code:

```
{{Form::open(['action' => ['HomeController@addcity'], 'method' => 'POST']) }} 

    {!! Form::select('city_option', array("CAM" => "CAM","KL" => "KL","IPOH" => "IPOH"),'S',['style'=>'color:red'],['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'hotel_name']); !!}
    {{Form::text('city_add',"CAM") }}
    {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```